# react native: can't find variable: define

Tags: react-native

I have a library that is written in `TypeScript`, that then has been compiled into one js file as an `amd` module.

I'm then trying to `import { Stuff } from 'that/library'`

but get an error message: `Can't find variable: define`;

can I not used AMD modules to import into my RN app?

**bonus question**: what bundling mechanism is used under the bonnet in `react-native`, it's clearly not Webpack..? and what types of modules are supported.

**edit**: just tried to recompile my library as System type module, that does not get recognised either `react native: can't find variable: System`;

Comment: I like bonus questions, that got me hyped up a little.

Comment: I'm seeing my answer partially answered here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native uses it's own packager, which relies on CommonJS (and ES6 Imports, transpiled by babel to, you guessed it, CommonJS). This answers both questions, UMD is not supported. There are different starter kits using webpack, though, if you would like to use it, for example [this one](https://github.com/jhabdas/react-native-webpack-starter-kit).